# Removing Rails 4.2 Deprecations from migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, deprecation-warning

I am going migrate my application to Rails 5. So I am now doing the process of removing all Rails 4.2 deprecation. I get the following deprecation warning

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: `#timestamps` was called without specifying an option for `null`. In Rails 5, this behavior will change to `null: false`. You should manually specify `null: true` to prevent the behavior of your existing migrations from changing. (called from block in up at
```

As all my migration files dos not have any

```
null: false
```

to my timestamps field, how can I avoid this deprecation from raising?

Comment: If you add `null: true` to all timestamp in all your migrations, the deprecation will gone.

Comment: Will this once again run my migrations? Or simpl changing this will by anyway affect my DB data as I am going to do this is production env also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may safely add `null: false` to all the timestamp fields in your migrations. This will not run migrations once again. All previously run migration ids are stored in the database table named `schema_migrations`. As long as this table contain corresponding migration id simple file amendment will not cause migration rerun.